# java - return String with switch case

Tags: java, switch-statement, return, expression, switch-expression

i tried to use an enum for my first time.
For some Tests i want to override the toString method of my enum and return a String with the chosen enum.

Heres my code so far:

```
@Override
public String toString()
{
    return "Fahrzeuge{" +
            switch(this)
            {
                case MOTORAD: "1"; break;
                case LKW: "2"; break;
                case PKW: "3"; break;
                case FAHRRAD: "4"; break;
            }
            +
            "typ:" + this.typ +
            ", ps:" + this.ps +
            ", reifen:" + this.reifen +
            ", gewicht:" + this.gewicht +
            "}";
}
```

IntelliJ underline my cases and tell me the following: "Not a Statement"
=> I guess this makes sense, if it's not allowed to build a String with a switch - case.

So far so good, but it seem's to be impossible to return a String which is build through a switch case, or did i make a mistake at my return?
Any other options to return the chosen enum?
I could add an attribute that hold my chosen enums name, but i though i could do this a bit simpler.

Thanks for help

Comment: "*So far so good, but it seem's to be impossible to return a String which is build through a switch case*" - How do you come to this conclusion? Do you get a compiler exception? A runtime exception? If so, please include the compiler error / stack trace. --- Two remarks: - Have you taken a look at [`Enum#ordinal()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Enum.html#ordinal())? - You should get used to write your code in english, at least as long as there are acceptable translations for your domain (`type`, `tires`, `hp`, `weight`, ...)

Comment: IntelliJ underline my cases and tell me the following: "Not a Statement"
Guess this makes sense, if it is not possible to return a switch case generated String.

Comment: ... Please include the compiler error by [edit]ing your question. One more remark: The code as-is does not seem extensible, thus violating the [Open-Closed Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open–closed_principle). I would suggest to transform the `Enum` into a class. Together with some [Builders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) you could achieve the same behaviour, but more extensible (e.g. your list is missing E-Scooters and tanks )

Comment: And two more: - in your `toString()`-implementation, you start the `String` with `"Fahrzeuge"` (`"vehicles"`, plural), but the `String` actually represents only ONE `"Fahrzeug"` (`"vehicle"`). - Attribute `reifen` (`tires`): this is too generic. Is this the type of tire? The brand? The amount? Be more specific, e.g. in your case `"anzahlReifen"` (`"numOfTires"`).

Comment: It's not important how much sense the names do. This code is just for me and some coding practice.
Thanks so far, but i can't see a solution for my question here.

Comment: Well.. those are comments, not answer, aren't they ? [Oscar answered your question already](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57833576/4216641). I question your overall design, i.e. the usage of an `Enum` in this way, and reviewed your code.

Comment: Why does your enum have fields for everything except the number? Just add it and you'll be fine. Also, it's "Motorrad" with two "r"s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you really don't need the switch Statement because the superclass of the enum already knows the name of your "type":

```
@Override
public String toString()
{
    return "Fahrzeuge: " + super.toString() +
            ", ps:" + this.ps +
            ", reifen:" + this.reifen +
            ", gewicht:" + this.gewicht;
}
```

Simply call the toString() method of the super class and you get the string value of your currently selected enum-type. You even can delete your type string.

Comment: Thanks, this is the solution i was looking for!
But i also learned that a switch should't be codet on the right side of an expression :)

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to return the value of a `switch` statement starting with Java 12, as per [JEP 325](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/325). Check your version of Java, if it's anything less than 12 then you can't use `switch` like that and you'll have to resort to first saving the intended value in a local variable. My point is, if your version of java is older than 12, then you have to do this:

```
String num = "";
switch (this)
{
    case MOTORAD:
        num = "1";
        break;
    case LKW:
        num = "2";
        break;
    case PKW:
        num = "3";
        break;
    case FAHRRAD:
        num = "4";
        break;
}

return "Fahrzeuge{" + num +
            "typ:" + this.typ +
            ", ps:" + this.ps +
            ", reifen:" + this.reifen +
            ", gewicht:" + this.gewicht +
            "}";
```

But if you have Java 12 (or above) installed, then you can do this (notice the different syntax!):

```
return "Fahrzeuge{" +
            switch (this)
            {
                case MOTORAD -> "1";
                case LKW     -> "2";
                case PKW     -> "3";
                case FAHRRAD -> "4";
            }
            + "typ:" + this.typ +
            ", ps:" + this.ps +
            ", reifen:" + this.reifen +
            ", gewicht:" + this.gewicht +
            "}";
```

And *do* notice that if the numbers correspond to the order in which the enum values were declared, you can simply use `ordinal()`:

```
return "Fahrzeuge{" + this.ordinal() +
            "typ:" + this.typ +
            ", ps:" + this.ps +
            ", reifen:" + this.reifen +
            ", gewicht:" + this.gewicht +
            "}";
```

Comment: For reference: this JEP is part of [Project Amber](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/amber/) (can't wait for its GA)

Comment: The switch(this) works well for me in any other method.
The Problem ist, that i can't build my return String with a switch - case to get a part of the String.

Comment: Yes, that's what my answer states: you can't use it as part of an expression (such as `return`) in older versions of Java. To be sure: what version are you using?

Comment: @lain91 as was stated, the default switch is a [statement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statement_(computer_science)), not an [expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expression_(computer_science)). Statements do not have values, thus you cannot use them on the right side of an assignment.

Comment: @ÓscarLópez ah okay, now i get it. thanks
I use the default settings at IntelliJ which is SDK - 12 (guess this is Java - 12 ? )

Comment: @lain91 check all my answer, jut try the three options. If the second one works, then yes, you have installed Java 12 :) . But personally, I'd prefer to use the third option.